# Visual Studio Code: settings.json family of C_Cpp.xxx configurations vs c_cpp_properties.json?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm pretty new to using the C/C++ Extension for VSCode. I'm confused what the precise roles and relationships are between configurations defined in the `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file and the `C_Cpp.xxx` family of settings allowed in the `settings.json` file.

Do these two mechanisms allow the configuration of the same settings just under different precedence rules or something?

Answer (score 5):

So there is a precedence relationship apparently: the `C_Cpp.xxx` family of settings serve as global defaults that can serve as a user level default (`~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`) or a folder level default if so configured.

The relationship is covered in this documentation: [(Customizing default settings)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp)

> You can override the default values for properties set in c_cpp_properties.json

Would probably have been better understood if written as:

> You can override the default values for properties defined in `settings.json` with those set in `c_cpp_properties.json`.

The understanding here being that there's a name correspondence and matching between the two contexts. The language in the documentation seems to denote stuff in `settings.json` with the terminology of *"VS Code settings"*.

This makes more sense when you actually manage to create a `c_cpp_properties.json` in a workspace by invoking one of the commands:
[image: c_cpp_properties.json creating command]

Then you'll find the newly generated file in your `.vscode` folder
[image: c_cpp_properties.json generated in .vscode folder]

The default config when editing via JSON renders on my mac as...

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Just for reference all the itemized Cpp configurations are laid out here [(c_cpp_properties.json reference)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference), the mapping going as:

```json
// settings.json
{
    C_cpp.default.<configName> : <configValue>
}
```

==>

```json
// c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "MyLocalConfig",
        <configName>:<configValue>,
    }
}
```

Comment: What a convoluted mess.